# `--database` is not working in "Artisan::call" method in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

I am using to set database dynamically and running migration to update database to create all table. with below command

```
Artisan::call("migrate",['--database'=>'new_database','--path'=>'database/migrations/company']);
```

But I am always getting this error

> 1/1 InvalidArgumentException in DatabaseManager.php line 239: Database
>   [new_database] not configured.

In my database.php is have created connection as

```
'company' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => '',
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

Pleas help me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

`Artisan::call("migrate",['--database'=>'company','--path'=>'database/migrations/company']);`

Answer (score 0):

The --database parameter for the migrate command specifies the database connection (not the database name) on which the migration command will run.

Do you have the 'new_database' connection defined in your database.php file?

Also, how do you set the database dinamically? Make sure the code that handles this runs before the artisan command is executed.